# HTML automatic site login filling. value with no parameters

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, craigslist

The website im trying to login to has the following username field

```
 <input type="text" id="inputEmailHandle" name="inputEmailHandle" value>
```

Im using Zombie Headless browser and nodejs, Zombie cannot find the input field named "inputEmailHandle" so i cannot automatically log in, i think its because of the `value>`
is there anyway i can get around it? or does anyone know a good way to do this with javascript and nodeJS?

ps the website im trying to log into is craigslist

Here's the code

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("https://accounts.craigslist.org", function () {
  browser.
    fill("inputEmailHandle", "person@email.com").
    fill("inputPassword", "password").
    pressButton("button", function() {
      console.log("LOGGED INNNNN!!!");
      assert.ok(browser.success);
    })
});
```

Comment: This looks like invalid HTML. I guess the Zombie Headless browser isn't too smart. Can you report a bug?

Comment: Could you show the code you are using? Also, have you tried running the same code in a regular browser?

Comment: @sabof i updated the post with the code

Answer (score 0):

The website is running iso-8859-1 encoding, which is apparently not supported by zombie... that is why its not finding anything